# What would I use when in need of a dynamicly adjusting multidemnsional list?

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I have a list that I want to function as a dynamically expanding tree-view, but if I am to have multiple lists inside of a list I need to declare that in the initial list's definition. What am I missing to accomplish this and is there something better to use to accomplish my goal?

For the sake of context: I am trying to populate it like a tree view so that I may replicate the registry within my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct type for your scenario.

In your case, this is a class `TreeNode` like so:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    private readonly List<TreeNode> _children = new List<TreeNode>();

    public TreeNode(string name, params TreeNode[] children)
    {
        Name = name;
        _children.AddRange(children);
    }

    public List<TreeNode> Children { get { return _children; } }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Assume the following tree:

```
Root
+ Child1
  + Child1a
  + Child1b
+ Child2
  + Child2a
    + Child2aA
    + Child2aB
  + Child2b
```

You would create it like so:

```
var root = new TreeNode("Root",
                        new TreeNode("Child1",
                                     new TreeNode("Child1a"),
                                     new TreeNode("Child1b")),
                        new TreeNode("Child2",
                                     new TreeNode("Child2a",
                                                  new TreeNode("Child2aA"),
                                                  new TreeNode("Child2aB")),
                                     new TreeNode("Child2b")));
```

Comment: So I would create my own TreeNode class as you posted and use it as I would the regularly available class?

Comment: The issue I am having here and maybe I am just not using the object correctly, but how would I go about the dynamic part of adding child after child after child to a pre-existing object? example: registryTreeTracker.Children.AddRange(rootSubs); where rootSubs is an array of strings, or just a normal add to add individual nodes in?

Comment: Okay I played around with it a little bit and figured out how to work it. Thank you very much this was a huge help!

Comment: Okay I thought I had it but I guess I am still a little muddy. How do I add more children to a pre-existing child in the object?

Comment: @JBeck: You could hold a reference to it by not creating it "inline" as I show in my example. Or you could get the child by using the `Children` property: `root.Children.Single("Child1").Children.AddRange(...);` This would add some children to `"Child1"`.

Comment: @JBeck: The second approach could be made more comfortable by providing an indexer on `TreeNode` that takes the children's name. In that case, it could look like so: `root["Child1"].Children.AddRange(...);`

Comment: Ah okay! I will try that and comment here how it goes. I am making progress though in the right direction, so definite thanks again! :)

Comment: Okay I've arrived at another impasse. I need to be able to keep going down through the indexes depending on how many children there will be, but I will never know how many children there will be. So if I do a for to iterate based on how many children there are I can't really go MyTreeNode.Children[i].Children[i].Children... See the problem? Any suggestions as to how to make this dynamic so I can keep adding children without being dependent on knowing exactly how many I need?

Comment: @JBeck: Well, at some point in time you need to know how deep you want to go. And you can write a recursive method that takes in a TreeNode and calls itself with each child. Like this you can walk down the tree without knowing how deep it is. If that doesn't help you, please post a new question with the *concrete* problem you are facing and post the link here in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576269/dynamicly-adjusting-tree-populated-with-registry-values