# Dynamicly Adjusting Tree populated with registry values

Tags: c#, dynamic, tree, registry

I am attempting to populate a tree structure with everything from the registry in string form so that I may use it to make comparisons to changes later on. So far I've come to an impasse with actually providing dynamic additions of children to the tree structure as I can never be certain as to how many children a subkey in the registry is going to have! Or how many values it will have, so I have to be able to dynamically populate the tree structure without knowing how many children there will ever be.

So far I have this:

```
    private void buildRegistryListTreeFromScratch(string[] rootSubs) {
        //The rootSubs argument is the first layer of subkeys directly underneath the root keys
        RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser;

        registryTreeTracker.Name = "Current User";

        for (int i = 0; i < rootSubs.Length; i++) {
            registryTreeTracker.Children.Add(new RegistryTreeNode(rootSubs[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rootSubs.Length; i++) {
            RegistryKey selectedKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(rootSubs[i]);
            if (selectedKey.SubKeyCount > 0) {
                subKeyBelow(rootSubs[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    private void subKeyBelow(string path) {
        RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        RegistryKey selectedKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < registryTreeTracker.Children.Count; i++){
            if (registryTreeTracker.Children[i].Name == path) {
                registryTreeTracker.Children[i] ... //This is the impasse I have reached
            }
        }
    }
```

the class I am using for the object registryTreeTracker is a class provided to me by Daniel Hilgarth in a question related to this, and its definition is as follows:

```
public class RegistryTreeNode {
    private readonly List<RegistryTreeNode> _children = new List<RegistryTreeNode>();

    public RegistryTreeNode(string name, params RegistryTreeNode[] children) {
        Name = name;
        _children.AddRange(children);
    }

    public List<RegistryTreeNode> Children {
        get {
            return _children;
        }
    }
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in subKeyBelow? You can add children to the tree using the same method you use in the first for loop: `registryTreeTracker.Children.Add`.

Comment: You can export your registry into .reg file and compare it using WinDiff. But this is crazy because your registry constantly changes. You can put monitoring on your registry using sys internals tools, which can report to you all registry events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a recursive method to build your tree. This method would receive the root key of the current level of the tree as well as the registry key that should be added to that root key.
It would look something like this:

```
public TreeNode AddChildNode(TreeNode parent, string name)
{
    var child = new TreeNode(name);
    parent.Children.Add(child);
    return child;
}

public void AddSubTree(TreeNode treeRoot, RegistryKey registryKeyToAdd)
{
    var child = AddChildNode(treeRoot, registryKeyToAdd.Name);

    foreach(var subKeyName in registryKeyToAdd.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        try
        {
            AddSubTree(child, registryKeyToAdd.OpenSubKey(subKeyName));
        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            AddChildNode(child, string.Format("{0} - Access denied", subKeyName));
        }
    }
}

public TreeNode BuildRegistryTree()
{
    var root = new TreeNode("Computer");
    AddSubTree(root, Registry.CurrentUser);
    AddSubTree(root, Registry.LocalMachine);
    return root;
}
```

You would call `BuildRegistryTree` to get the complete tree.

Comment: I am currently working on that right now after I gave your comment in the last question some thought! I will be posting the results once I am done, but it is basically in a similar direction as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a more conclusive question here is the culmination of my work thanks to Daniel Hilgarth:

```
    //the rootSubs argument is a string array containing all the subkeys of the root keys
    private void buildRegistryListTreeFromScratch(string[] rootSubs) {

        RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser;

        registryTreeTracker.Name = "Current User";

        for (int i = 0; i < rootSubs.Length; i++) {
            registryTreeTracker.Children.Add(new RegistryTreeNode(rootSubs[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rootSubs.Length; i++) {
            RegistryKey selectedKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(rootSubs[i]);
            if (selectedKey.SubKeyCount > 0) {
                subKeyBelow(rootSubs[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void subKeyBelow(string path) {
        RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        RegistryKey selectedKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(path);


        for (int i = 0; i < registryTreeTracker.Children.Count; i++){
            if (registryTreeTracker.Children[i].Name == path) {
                recursiveSubKeyBelow(registryTreeTracker.Children[i], path);
            }
        }
    }

    private void recursiveSubKeyBelow(RegistryTreeNode currentNode, string path) {
        RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        RegistryKey selectedKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(path);
        string originalPath = path;
        RegistryKey originalKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(originalPath);

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedKey.SubKeyCount; i++){
        currentNode.Children.Add(new RegistryTreeNode(selectedKey.GetSubKeyNames()[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < originalKey.SubKeyCount; i++) {
            string deeperPath = originalPath + "\\" + originalKey.GetSubKeyNames()[i];
            try {
                selectedKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(deeperPath);
                if (selectedKey.SubKeyCount > 0) {
                    recursiveSubKeyBelow(currentNode.Children[i], deeperPath);
                }
            } catch(SecurityException) {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks loads Dan! With your suggestions/help this problem became a lot more manageable!

Comment: You are welcome, but your solution is - needlessly - a lot more complex, less versatile and less performant than mine. Why did you choose to use this approach and not what I showed you? The code I posted in my answer is complete - with the exception that it doesn't handle security exceptions. However, your handling of security exceptions looks strange, because it seems to also skip the key *after* the one that threw the security exception.

Comment: BTW: I understand you are still learning, so I really like that you tried and succeeded in getting to a solution on your own. But in order to learn even more, try to study my answer in detail and compare it with your answer. Understand what the shortcomings of your answer are and improve it.

Comment: I definitely see what you are talking about that it is needlessly complex, and the reason I ended up using it is because I had already written most of it by the time you posted your much more elegant answer. I will definitely try(If I have the time in the middle of this project.) to implement and sharpen up my code in a similar spirit to yours! Thanks a bunch again! :)